# Translating "good lives" in the plural

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammatical-number

I am writing an essay and want to say in German

> "Gandhi and Mandela had good lives, in the sense that millions of
> other people had a better life because they had lived."

but I am getting myself confused. Can one say

> "Gandhi und Mandela hatten ein gutes Leben....."

as Google Translate suggests? To me this sounds like they had one life between them. Or is

> "Gandhi und Mandela hatten beide ein gutes Leben....."

better? How could I use "life" in the plural? Like this?

> "Gandhi und Mandela hatten gute Leben....."

One additional question: Should one use life or lives ("das Leben oder Die Leben") in the second part of the sentence?

> "........in the sense that millions of other people had a better life
> because they had lived."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

German is much less picky about possessives in the plural than English, for example.

While English would be very precise about the number of bicycles such as

> All the boys in our neighborhood went to school on their bicycles

German is much less precise - even if "Fahrrad" is singular in the following example,

> Die Jungs in unsrer Nachbarschaft fuhren alle mit ihrem Fahrrad in die Schule

it is clear that that it is more than one bicycle we're talking about - and no native speaker would even rise an eyebrow about this.

In your example, the most natural way to express what you want in German would indeed be

> Gandhi und Mandela hatten ein gutes Leben in dem Sinn, dass Millionen anderer Menschen aufgrund ihres Daseins ein besseres Leben genießen konnten.

No native speaker would assume the two guys *shared one life*. You shouldn't, however, understand that we automatically assume two instances - We take the amount of lives from context. If they would try and share a cake, we'd probably be assuming differently.

In the case of *lives*, plural - in both parts of the sentence - would really sound awkward. And note I have replaced the second "Leben" with "Dasein" to avoid the repetition. You'd probably even want to use "Taten"